# 'require is not defined' error when trying to set up .env file

Tags: javascript, firebase, npm, firebase-realtime-database, environment-variables

I’m trying to set up a `.env` file to store the credentials to my Firebase database in a vanilla JS project. I’ve followed a few tutorials and the docs for [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) but I am still getting an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. What am I missing?

Here's what I have in `<script>`tags in my `index.html` file. The credentials are in `.env`.

```js
require('dotenv').config();
// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Comment: `require` is a Node.js function. It can't be used client-side. `process` is also not something that's accessible in browsers. You'e getting client-side and server-side javascript mixed-up.

Answer (score 2):

Browser didn't have require function if you want to use require in browser use tools like [browserify](http://browserify.org/)

dotenv is node module which requires fs module to read .env file you can't use it in browser

Comment: Is there another way to set up and use `.env` files without having to use something like browserify/webpack etc. ?

Comment: you can't use .env files in browser